# Adding event handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to obtain an individual person when a user clicks on the form. I tried adding an event handler into the return section of the code but i need to implement something like 

onClick={props.click}

 in the Person class. 
Also can anyone recommend some react with typescript tutorials.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface HelloWorldI {
    persons: ReadonlyArray<PersonI>,
    showPersons: boolean
}

interface PersonI {
    name: string,
    age: number,
}

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<{}, HelloWorldI> {
    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props)
        const p: ReadonlyArray<PersonI> = [
            { name: 'Max', age: 28},
            { name: 'Max', age: 28 },       
        ]
        this.state = {
            persons: p,
            showPersons: false
        }   
    }

    deletePersonHandler = (personIndex:any) => {
        const persons = this.state.persons;
        persons.slice(personIndex, 1);
        this.setState({ persons: persons });

    }

    togglePersonsHandler = () => {
        const doesShow:any = this.state.showPersons;
        this.setState({ showPersons: !doesShow });
    }

    public render() {
        let persons = null;

        if (this.state.showPersons) {
            persons = (
                <div>
                    {this.state.persons.map((person,index) => {
                        return <Person 
                           onClick={this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
                            name={person.name}
                            age={person.age} />
                    })}
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}></button>  
                    {persons}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Person extends React.Component<{ name: string, age: number }, {}>     {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p> {this.props.name} and {this.props.age} </p>)
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is easy to do. Ill post an answer shortly if someone else doesn't get to it first.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this, would be to pass an anonymous arrow function as a prop down to each Person Component. You can't pass an argument to deletePersonHandler the way you currently are.

Instead, try something like this:

```
{
  this.state.persons.map((person,index) => {
  return (
      <Person 
        delete={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
        name={person.name}
        age={person.age} 
      />
    )
  })
}
```

Then, in your Person Component, attach the onClick event like so:

```
class Person extends React.Component<{ name: string, age: number }, {}>     {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.delete}>
        <p> {this.props.name} and {this.props.age} </p>)
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/vRNBEO?editors=0011) is an example somewhat similar to what you are trying to do that I made in Codepen. Click each person in the HTML section and check what happens in the console.

P.S. I don't use TypeScript at all, but remember you need to also declare your function being passed down in the arguments section of the Person Component.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I wrote the code using react first  and it worked ok, now i am trying to do it using typescript but i am having alot of difficulty.

Comment: Yeah I don't use TypeScript, so unfortunately I don't think I can help any further.

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the type try something like `class Person extends React.Component<{ name: string, age: number,  deleteHandlerFn: (number) => void }, {}> {`